# What is the expected number of flips of a fair coin before seeing both $HH$ and $TT$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, markov-chains, markov-process

I flip an unbiased coin (The probabilities $p$ of heads and $q$ of tails are both $\frac{1}{2}$.) How many flips until I obtain both HH and TT in any order?

My approach is as follows:
Let E be expected number of flips. The possibilities are

A:  HH Flips  $=  2p^2$

B:  HT Flips  $=  (1+E)pq$

C:  TT Flips  $=  2q^2$

D:  TH Flips  $=  (1+E)pq$

Equating gives $E =  ( A + B + C + D )$. For $p = q = \frac{1}{2}$ the value of $E$ is $3$ flips total.

I want to know if this correct.

Using a similar method I know the number of flips to get HH is $6$ and the number of flips to get TT is also $6$ so my solution of $3$ seems weird. I am not sure if my solution is correct for either HH or TT.

Comment: How can you throw both $HH$ and $TT$ in $3$ tosses?

Comment: @lulu: you are correct .  Maybe my equation is the flips for getting either HH or TT. Am I correct about this ?  
 If this is the case I still would like to know flips total to get both HH and TT . Maybe I can just add 6 + 6 but I dont believe this is correct .

Comment: I can't follow your calculation, so I can't help with that method.  I suggest:  Use states.  Keep track of whether or not you have already seen $HH$ or $TT$ and what the last flip was.  If you stick with a fair coin, there are lots symmetries between these so the computation is easy.

Comment: Note:  a fast way to get to the answer is ask for the expected number of tosses until you see *either* $HH$ or $TT$, then add $6$.  Again, this trick only works easily for a fair coin.

Comment: I believe my solution of 3 is for either HH or TT. Then i would add 6 to this for a total of 9 . Do you agree ?

Comment: I agree that the correct answer is $9$ for a fair coin.  As I say, I can't follow your calculation so I can't tell if you solved the "either" case correctly or not (the answer to that case is indeed $3$).

Answer (score 3):

This exercise is a typical application of a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).

We can model our system with $5$ states:

- $0$: the initial state
- $A$: at least $1$ toss, and neither $HH$ nor $TT$ has occurred yet
- $B$: exactly $1$ of $HH$ and $TT$ have occurred, and the last toss matches the pair that has already occurred (e.g., $HH$ has occurred but $TT$ has not, and the last toss was an $H$)
- $C$: exactly $1$ of $HH$ and $TT$ have occurred, and the last toss matches the pair that has not yet occurred (e.g., $HH$ has occurred but $TT$ has not, and the last toss was an $T$)
- $1$: both $HH$ and $TT$ have occurred (so, $1$ is the sole absorbing state) .

We can compute the probabilities of transitions between states using the description of the problem. For example, if you toss a coin while in state A,

- with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ your next toss does not coincide with your previous toss, and so you remain in state $A$, and
- with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ your next toss coincides with your previous state, and so you move to state $B$.

At this point the problem is routine: We can construct the stochastic transition matrix for the process from the probabilities above (using the state order $0, A, B, C, 1$), which we'll write in a block decomposition with block sizes $4, 1$:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
S & {\bf a} \\
\hline
\cdot & 1
\end{array}
\right)$$
The upper-left $4 \times 4$ minor $S$ records the transition probabilities between transient states, and, for example, our previous observation about the possible transitions from state $A$ show that $S_{22} = \Bbb P(A \leftarrow A) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $S_{23} = \Bbb P(B \leftarrow A) = \frac{1}{2}$. We start in state $0$, so the initial distribution vector is $$\tau := \pmatrix{1&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot},$$ and thus the expected time to reach the absorbing state is
$$\bar t = \tau (I - S')^{-1} {\bf 1} ,$$ where $\bf 1$ is the $4 \times 1$ vector with all entries $1$.

> For our process carrying out this computation gives $\boxed{\bar t = 9}$.

**Remark** Once our process reaches $A$ it never goes back to $0$, and likewise once it reaches $B$ it never goes back to $A$ or $B$. So, we can split our Markov process into three simpler processes---one for the transition from  $0$ to $A$, another for the transition from $A$ to $B$, and third for the movement from $B$ to $1$---in which case the linearity of expectation gives that $\bar t$ is just the sum of the expected durations $\bar t\!_{0A}, \bar t\!_{AB}, \bar t\!_{B1}$ of each of the constituent process. In particular, the computation you mentioned can be adapted to show that moving from $B$ to $1$ takes an average of $\bar t\!_{B1} = 6$ steps, which reduces the original problem to computing $\bar t\!_{0A}$ and $\bar t\!_{AB}$. In both cases the constituent Markov chains have exactly $2$ states, start in the sole transient state and at each step move to the sole absorbing state with some probability $r$: Specializing the above formula gives an expected time of $\frac{1}{r}$ steps to reach the absorbing state.

> So, $\bar t\!_{0A} = \frac{1}{(1)} = 1$ steps and $\bar t\!_{AB} = \frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)} = 2$ steps, giving $\bar t = 1 + 2 + 6 = \boxed{9}$.

Comment: thank you could you please write out the 5 x5  transition matrix and label the states . Would prefer in terms of p and q where  q =  1-p .If you dont desire to use p and q , just display 1/2 or 1 where appropriate. Thank you.

Comment: Is this a correct interpretation of linearity of expection. First it will take 1 step to go from initial state to either a H or T. This happens with probability 1.0 . Now I am in your state A. Now assuming your probability  r it will take 1/r = 2 steps to get a doublet whether it is HH or TT- ie H>H or T>T. Once i have this Original doublet -either HH or TT- it will then take 6 steps to get the next doublet- ie TT If HH Is the first or vice versa.

Comment: The example computations in the problem show that the second row of the transition matrix---the one governing transitions from state A---is
$\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}\cdot&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&\cdot&\cdot\end{array}\right) .$ In particular this solution takes advantage of the symmetry $p = q$ that the coin is fair. If $p \neq q$ that symmetry breaks and you'll need to states $A, B, C$ into $2$ states each.

Comment: Yes, that's basically correct, with the proviso that the modifier "on average" is inserted in appropriate places; in short you're just computing finer information. In fact, the $i$th row of $(I - S)^{-1}$ is by construction the expected number of steps you spend in each transient state if you start in the $i$th state, so the entries of $\tau (I - S)^{-1} = \pmatrix{1&2&4&2}$ are the expected numbers of steps you spend in each state if you start in state $0$, and thus the expected total duration before reaching an absorbing state is $\tau (I - S)^{-1} {\bf 1} = 1 + 2 + 4 + 2 = 9$ steps.